# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 0 supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Ошибка `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 0 supplied.`

При попьітке вьіполнить єту функцию:

```
def click(self, user_id: int):
    with self.conn:
        setting = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user_setting WHERE user_id =?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
        amount = setting[1] * setting[2]
        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE wallet SET uah = uah + ? WHERE user_id = ?"), (amount, user_id)
        self.conn.commit()
```

Пьітался найти решение в Гугле, не нашел. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Скобка перед запятой в строке с UPDATE.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я просрал 3 часа из-за какой-то скобки... 
В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: "Всего лишь" три часа...